# Handlebars array access with dynamic index

Tags: handlebars.js

How can I access to an array element inside handlebars template using a variable instead of an hardcoded value?
I need to do something like:

```
{{#each condition in conditions}}
    {{App.ops.[condition.op].name}}
{{/each}}
```

at the moment doesn't give me a parse error but on runtime doesn't return me nothing.
If i do something like this:

```
{{App.ops.[1].name}}
```

it works but it's not what i'm looking for

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Related to [my answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32640060/2712445)

---

You can use [the built-in `lookup` helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup):

> The `lookup` helper allows for dynamic parameter resolution using Handlebars variables. This is useful for resolving values for array indexes.

Using `lookup`, your example could be written as

```
{{#each condition in conditions}}
    {{#with (lookup ../App.ops condition.op)}}
        {{name}}
    {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

(Note that without knowledge of the structure of your data, I'm making an assumption about the location of `App.ops`.)

Comment: This solution works for me but I cannot use `{{#each condition in conditions}}` (I get an error: "Must pass iterator to #each"). Instead I have to write `{{#each conditions as |condition|}}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can write a simple helper just to get value from array

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getmyvalue', function(outer, inner) {
    return outer[inner.label];
});
```

and then use it in template like

```
{{#each outer}}
    {{#each ../inner}}
        {{getmyvalue ../this this }}
{{/each}}
```

`../this` references to current outer item, and `this` - to current inner item

Example of data coming to template:

```
{
    outer: {
        1: { foo: "foo value" },
        2: { bar: "bar value" }
    },
    inner: {
        1: { label: "foo" },
        2: { label: "bar" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a helper for your problem. Below is the sample solution to your problem using index values. If you want to use some conditions you can also do that.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("each_with_index", function(array, options) {
    if(array != undefined && array != null && array.length > 0){
        var html = new StringBuffer();
        for (var i = 0, j = array.length; i < j; i++) {
            var item = array[i];
            item.index = i+1;

            // show the inside of the block
            html.append(options.fn(item));
    }

    // return the finished buffer
    return html.toString();
}
return "";
});
```

Then you can do something like this

```
{{#each_with_index condition in conditions}}
    {{App.ops.[condition.index].name}}
{{/each_with_index}}
```