# How to get an array value at index using Handlebars.js?

Tags: handlebars.js

Say I have JSON:

```
{
userinput: [
    {name: "brian", "value": "i like pies"},
    {name: "susan", "value": "memes are stupid"}
],
feedback: [
    {value: "i also like pies"},
    {value: "null"}
]
}
```

And I'm trying to draw a table like this:

```
name ..... | input ......   | feedback
-----------|----------------|-----------------
brian      | I like pies    | I also like pies
susan      | mems are stupid| null
```

And while I recognise that it would be better to have feedback as a value of "userinput", what I have is not done like that ...

I'm trying to get the index of feedback inside {{#each userinput}}`, e.g.

```
{{#each userinput}}
<td>{{name}}</td><td>{{value}}</td><td>{{../feedback[@index].value}}</td>
{{/each}}
```

But of course `{{../feedback[@index].value}}` does not work.

What is the best way (without changing the structure of the json) to grab the value of the matching index inside the feedback array?

Comment: Hey frumbert, I noticed you haven't selected an answer. Just wanted to point out that, while @Rubens Mariuzzo didn't work for me, [nickgraef 's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32640060/923817) did.

Comment: @D.Tate at the time I was unable to upgrade handlebars since it used some javascript techniques that were too new for the javascript server side engine I was using; the version I had then didn't contain a lookup helper/method and did something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/18169209/1238884.

Answer (score 15):

This can be accomplished using [the `lookup` helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup):

> The `lookup` helper allows for dynamic parameter resolution using Handlebars variables. This is useful for resolving values for array indexes.

So the template for your example would look like this:

```
{{#each userinput}}
    <td>{{name}}</td>
    <td>{{value}}</td>
    <td>
        {{#with (lookup ../feedback @index)}}
            {{value}}
        {{/with}}
    </td>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: This seems to be the best answer! Works nicely for me! Thanks @nickgraef.

Comment: This is the best answer. Works like a charm.

Comment: ../ path segment is not obvious, but important here if "feedback" is from outside scope. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#path-expressions

Answer (score 3):

I guess you will have to write a block helper for this, as it seems `@index` can only be used as a stand-alone.

I modified the ["list" example](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html), to allow a template like this:  `"{{#list userinput feedback}}<td>{{name}}</td><td>{{value}}</td><td>{{@feedback.value}}</td>{{/list}}"`.  The implementation is like this, accepting two parameters "input" and "feedback" (plus the standard "options").

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('list', function(input, feedback, options) {
  var out = "", data;

  // iterate over the input
  for (var i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    if (options.data) {
      data = Handlebars.createFrame(options.data || {});

      // add "feedback" item to the current frame's data
      data.feedback = feedback[i];
    }

    out += "<tr>" + options.fn(input[i], { data: data }) + "</tr>";
  }

  return out;
});
```

[Here's the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/DnZ7c/6/)