# Handlebars.js - Access object value with a variable key

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Looking for a way to access to achieve this:

```
{{#each someArray}}
  {{../otherObject.[this]}}
{{/each}}
```

How do I evaluate the value of `this` and then reference it as a key to my object `otherObject`?

Comment: I have, searched for 2 days.  Maybe I'm just awful at googling.

Comment: [This one from the sidebar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168924/how-to-get-an-array-value-at-index-using-handlebars-js?rq=1) is about 90% of the solution. Basically, you have to write our own helper that converts things like `{{value_at obj key}}` to the JavaScript `obj[key]`.

Comment: I've seen that answer, the second one refers to what I'm talking about, and I was hoping for a similar solution because it seems like such an obvious use case.  It's hard to believe that handlebars doesn't support this syntax...

Comment: Did you find any workaround @KevinWang? I'm stuck on the same issue...

Answer (score 19):

With lookup: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup

```
{{#each someArray}}
  {{lookup ../otherObject this}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: best answer that is

Comment: this is printing [object Object]

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution with a helper:

```
/*
{{#each someArrayOfKeys}}
  {{#withItem ../otherObject key=this}}
    {{this}}
  {{/withItem}}
{{/each}}
*/

Handlebars.registerHelper('withItem', function(object, options) {
    return options.fn(object[options.hash.key]);
});
```