# Accessing another variable with contents of each loop

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars

The data being passed into the handlebars template looks like this:

```
a = {
    x: {
       name: "xavier"
    },
    y: {
       name: "yamal"
    },
}

b = {
    properties: {
        x: {
            property: "number"
        }
    }
}
```

Handlebars template looks like this:

```
<div class="left-panel">
    {{a.x.name}} // Prints correctly "xavier"
    {{#each b.properties}}
        <h4>{{@key}}</h4> // Prints correctly "x"
        <h4>{{ ../a.[@key].name }}</h4> // does not print "xavier"
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

As you can see, I want to be able to access the `name` of a dict in `a` using the key in `b`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I reckon you may need to create your own helper function to achieve this. I believe the reason it's not working in this context is because @key is being used as a 'string' (i.e. "x"), rather than a reference to attribute 'x'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is essentially the same as this one: [Handlebars.js - Access object value with a variable key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19646244/3397771)

The only extra detail is that you will need to make use of [Handlebars subexpressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions) in order to perform the two lookups (first of `@key`; then of `'name'`).

A subexpression will allow you to lookup the value of `@key` on `../a` and pass that to a second lookup of the value of `'name'` on the result of the first lookup.

The relevant line in your template becomes:

```
<h4>{{lookup (lookup ../a @key) 'name'}}</h4>
```

Here is a fiddle for your reference:
https://jsfiddle.net/76484/b0puy52n/