# Getting a property by using another property as key

Tags: handlebars.js, express-handlebars

Is it possible to get a property of an object having the key being another property?

Handlebars data:

```
{
   person: {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
   },
   propertyToGetFromPerson: 'firstName'
}
```

Then in the template itself I would like to get `firstName` of person but by using the `propertyToGetFromPerson` property in stead of the literal 'firstName'.

In JavaScript this would be: `person[propertyToGetFromPerson]`

So I am searching for the **equivalent in handlebars** if there is one.

I am looking for an **answer without using helpers**, if there is no answer I can write a helper.

Comment: You must use the `lookup` built-in helper. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup. Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54274111/3397771

Comment: @76484 Thanks a lot, it worked! I read this before on the docs but I interpreted it wrong. If you post this as an answer I can accept ;-)

Comment: I think this question, or variations on it, has been answered too many times already. In the interest of avoiding bloat on this site, I think it would be better if you found one of the existing answers and up-voted it.