# Is it possible to have a variable in a handlebars expression?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

If I have this handlebars template:

```
<p>{{array.0.title}}</p>
```

and this context

```
 array: [{title: First Title},
        {title: Second Title}]
```

It will output

```
<p>First Title</p>
```

Is it possible to dynamically change the 0 so that it will output

```
<p>Second Title</p>
```

Ideally, I would be able to use a variable such as index in the handlebar expression:

```
{{array.index.title}}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean typing `dynamically`.

Comment: Perhaps dynamically isn't the right word. What I'd like to do is select an option from a dropdown that changes the 0 to a 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array value at index using Handlebars.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168924/how-to-get-an-array-value-at-index-using-handlebars-js)